# Using will_paginate for finding which page an entry exists on

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, will-paginate

I'm trying to find a way to tell will_paginate what page to start on given an object and I'm having trouble finding any docs on it (Maybe there is no method in will_paginate??).

Here's my scenario:

The page where I display the item has 2 columns, the left one displaying 25 items at a time using will_paginate.

When the user clicks the email button, I generate outbound emails that contain a reentry link to that specific item. The link routes to my index page and passes the id of the object I want BUT I need to tell will_paginate what page to render since the item can exist on page 1, 2, 3, etc...

I know I can find all items and then find the rank of my current item and do some math but I was wondering if there was a better way i.e does will_paginate have any fun methods for doing something like this??

Thanks!

Comment: What about passing the params[:page] through the email button, so you can pass that in the email body link. That way you can link back to the same url with the page number. So long as your database query remains the same, it should work.

Comment: The problem is that the list I generate for page 1 generates the top 25 most recent items so say that the entry I sent an email out for was #24 on the list of page 1, then after 2 new items are created, it would now be on page 2... :P

Comment: Then what your talking about involves a lot more than just pagination, you would need to remember the full results.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah I got the issue.
Raise similar problem with me, In my case:-

**Work with me**

```
@posts = Post.all.order_by(:created_at)

@post = @posts.find_by(id: params[:id])

total_posts_count = @posts.where("posts.created_at <= ?", @post.created_at).count

@page = (total_posts_count/per_page.to_f).ceil

@posts = @posts.paginate(per_page: per_page, page: @page)
```

Logic here...

```
total_posts = 50
per_page = 25

50/25 = 2
```